# Replace "\\" with "/" in Java

Tags: java, android, replace

I am trying to replace `'\\'`with `'/'` in java(Android) and this does not seem to work!

```
String rawPath = filePath.replace("\\\\", "/");
```

What is wrong with this ? I have escaped "\" and tried escaping '/' but to no use. Nothing happens to the original string.

```
    filePath = abc\\xyz(not after escaping two \\, the original string is with two \\)
    rawPath = abc \ xyz
    expected = abc/xyz
```

Whats the correct way of doing this? (Another Windows file to Android path conversion prob)

Comment: Why not use `java.io.File.separator` throughout your code?

Comment: Yup - switching to that, just testing some stuff out for now and ran into this , thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When using `String.replace(String, String)` the backslash doesn't need to be escaped twice (thats when using `replaceAll` - it deals with regex). So:

```
String rawPath = filePath.replace("\\", "/");
```

Or using `char` version:

```
String rawPath = filePath.replace('\\', '/');
```

Comment: backslashes always need to be escaped in java. That has nothing to do with regex. Your suggestion will replace each `\\` with `/`.

Comment: A backslash in a String always needs to be escaped in your code unless you intend for it to be used as part of some other escape sequence.

Comment: ... twice, of course... (that is why I wrote the comment about `replaceAll`)

Comment: @dacwe I thought the question was about replacing a sequence of 2 backslashes in a string with a forward slash based on the given example. I might have misunderstood.

Comment: Thanks! Well basically what I had was , I was getting a string from my windows environment in this form `filepath = "abc\\xyz"` (only two '\\') and this worked like a charm

Answer (score 6):

You do not need the quad-druple escape,

> \\\\

, just simply

> \\

.

Answer (score 6):

escape with single slash should be enough. Following is working fine for me.

`String rawPath = filePath.replace("\\", "/");`

Answer (score 3):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "foo\\\\bar";
    System.out.println(s);
    System.out.println(s.replace("\\\\", "/"));     
}
```

will print

```
foo\\bar
foo/bar
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to replace a sequence of 2 backslashes in your original string with a single forward slash, this should work:

```
String filePath = "abc\\\\xyz";
String rawPath = filePath.replace("\\\\", "/");

System.out.println(filePath);
System.out.println(rawPath);
```

outputs:

```
abc\\xyz  
abc/xyz
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you really have two backslashes in the String in the first place? That only appears in Java source code. At runtime there will only be one backslash. So the task reduces to changing backslashes to forward slashes (why?). For which you need a regex if you are using `replaceAll()`, which would require four of them: two for the compiler, and two for the regex, but you aren't using that, you are using `replace()`, which isn't a regex, so you only need two, one for the compiler and one for itself.

Why are you doing this? It is never necessary to use a backslash in a File path in Java at all, and it is also never necessary to translate them to / unless you are doing URL-like things with them, in which case there are `File.toURI()` methods and URI and URL classes for that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very small method to get the desktop path and show you how to replace them in the return statement.

```
    public static String getDesktopPath() {

      String desktopPath = System.getProperty("user.home") + "/Desktop";
      return desktopPath.replace("\\", "/");

}
```