# How to replace backslash("\\\\") from JSON document?

Tags: java, json, string, replaceall

I have the complex json body which contains a lot of "\\ (pair of 4 backslashes)"  and "(single backslash)" . I want to replace the "\\" with "/ (single slash)" and it is working but the problem is it is also replacing the "\" from my json document which is destructing my document .

How do I replace only "\\" and not "\" using Java ??

Currently I am using :

```
String fileContent = fileContent.replaceAll("\\\\", "/");
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: did u find `regex` can help?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11509476/replace-with-in-java/11509502

Comment: `replaceAll(String regex, String replacement)` vs `replace(CharSequence target, CharSequence replacement)` or `replace(char old, char new)`

Comment: @Donald Wu What sort of regex you are saying about ?

Comment: `replaceAll(String regex, String replacement)` this func can replace regex inside..u can use this site to test the regex: https://regexr.com/

Comment: Because you are using `replaceAll` rather than `replace` (both of them replace all occurrences, but `replaceAll` takes a regex and `replace` takes a simple string), your four backslashes are interpreted as just one backslashes. use `replace` instead.

Answer (score 1):

For all clearness, a non-regex replace of two backslashes would be:

```
String fileContent = fileContent.replace("\\\\", "/"); // Two backslashes to /.
```

Using regex replaceAll is a PITA, as 4 backslashes represent `\\` which in regex represents 1 backslash:

```
String fileContent = fileContent.replaceAll("\\\\\\\\", "/");
```

Answer (score -2):

try like below to get the expected output

> String fileContent = fileContent.replace("\\", "/");

Comment: Using replace is the key. However the OP wanted to replace two backslashes with / - if I am not mistaken. That is to be seen. A bit of explanation would be nice also. Place the code on a separate line, after an empty line, with an indentation of 4 spaces. Thanks for the contribution